# Как вставить два таймера обратного отсчёта на javascript на одну страницу?

Tags: таймер, javascript

Есть счётчик обратного отсчёта на яваскрипт (`Countdown.js`):

```
//Скрипт обратного отсчета времени CountDown

var eventstr = "<span class='countDown1RED'>Вы опоздали</span>"; //Эта строка выводиться по окончанию отсчета
var countdownid = document.getElementById("countdown"); //ID элемента в который выводится время

var montharray=new Array("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec");

function CountDowndmn(yr,m,d){
    cdyear=yr;
    cdmonth=m;
    cdday=d;
    var today=new Date();
    var todayy=today.getYear();
    if (todayy < 1000)
    todayy+=1900;
    var todaym=today.getMonth();
    var todayd=today.getDate();
    var todayh=today.getHours();
    var todaymin=today.getMinutes();
    var todaysec=today.getSeconds();
    var todaystring=montharray[todaym]+" "+todayd+", "+todayy+" "+todayh+":"+todaymin+":"+todaysec;
    futurestring=montharray[m-1]+" "+d+", "+yr
    dd=Date.parse(futurestring)-Date.parse(todaystring);
    dday=Math.floor(dd/(60*60*1000*24)*1);
    dhour=Math.floor((dd%(60*60*1000*24))/(60*60*1000)*1);
    dmin=Math.floor(((dd%(60*60*1000*24))%(60*60*1000))/(60*1000)*1);
    dsec=Math.floor((((dd%(60*60*1000*24))%(60*60*1000))%(60*1000))/1000*1);
    if(dday<=0&&dhour<=0&&dmin<=0&&dsec<=1){
    countdownid.innerHTML=eventstr;
return
}
else {
    var lastchar = ""+dsec; lastchar = lastchar.substring(lastchar.length-1,lastchar.length);
    var dsecstr = "с";
    if (lastchar=="1") { dsecstr = "с"; }
    if ((lastchar=="2")||(lastchar=="3")||(lastchar=="4")) { dsecstr = "с"; }

    lastchar = ""+dmin; lastchar = lastchar.substring(lastchar.length-1,lastchar.length);
    var dminstr    = "м";
    if (lastchar=="1") { dminstr = "м"; }
    if ((lastchar=="2")||(lastchar=="3")||(lastchar=="4")) { dminstr = "м"; }

    lastchar = ""+dhour;    lastchar = lastchar.substring(lastchar.length-1,lastchar.length);
    var dhourstr   = "ч";
    if (lastchar=="1") { dhourstr = "ч"; }
    if ((lastchar=="2")||(lastchar=="3")||(lastchar=="4")) { dhourstr = "ч"; }

    lastchar = ""+dday; lastchar = lastchar.substring(lastchar.length-1,lastchar.length);
    var ddaystr = "д";
    if (lastchar=="1") { ddaystr = "д"; }
    if ((lastchar=="2")||(lastchar=="3")||(lastchar=="4")) { ddaystr = "д"; }

    countdownid.innerHTML= dday+" "+ddaystr+" : "+dhour+" "+dhourstr+" : "+dmin+" "+dminstr+" : "+dsec+" "+dsecstr;

}
setTimeout("CountDowndmn(cdyear,cdmonth,cdday)",1000);
}

CountDowndmn(2013,06,10); //Дата отсчета: год, месяц, число
```

А также код, который выводит сам счётчик на странице в диве:

```
<DIV align="center" ID="countdown"></DIV>
<SCRIPT src="scripts/Countdown.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></SCRIPT>
```

Если вставляю счётчик в двух местах на странице, то один счётчик перестаёт работать.
Как этот счётчик можно вставить на страницу в двух разных местах?

Comment: Id должен быт разные.

Comment: Ну это понятно. У меня и ID, и файлы счётчика для каждого дива разные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А может быть, [не стоит изобретать велосипед?](https://github.com/hilios/jQuery.countdown)

Comment: А какой велосипед я изобретаю?

Comment: Это не то, что мне нужно. Там таймер не берёт время с компа пользователя. А будет вести отсчёт со времени захода на сайт, если убрать выбор времени. А скрипт, предоставленный выше, то, что нужно. И это готовый скрипт, который писал не я. Так что о изобретении какого велосипеда речь, чне не понятно.

Comment: чтобы взять время с компа пользователя, можно использовать new Date() и далее подставить его в плагин. а вообще, учите джаваскрипт и научитесь принимать конструктивные советы, даже если они вам не нравятся.

Comment: Для чего человеку, который не является программистом, учить яваскрипт? Только для того, чтобы вставить счётчик?

Comment: спрашивать на профильном форуме программистов "зачем мне учить язык" сопоставимо с походом в Гарлем с плакатом "ненавижу ниггеров"

Comment: почему человек, который не является программистом вставляет счетчик. Извините бесплатный саппорт окончен. **я помогаю и вообще считаю людьми, только тем у кого есть память и кто не спросит меня одно и то-же 10 раз.**